# Get only the value of an element in an R data frame (without the index)

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

I have a small data frame lie this:

```
> testdfcompound_1
                            E1          E2
2012-05-17 01:00:58   20.94700    2.148299
2012-05-17 01:01:57   15.36875    2.199166
2012-05-17 01:02:56   19.05800    2.697803
2012-05-17 01:03:55   17.90500    2.358735
```

And I want to get only the E1 value of the 1st element, so, 20.94700.

But I can't find a way to get it. If I try: `testdfcompound_1$E1[1]`, I'm getting:

```
> testdfcompound_1$E1[1]
                        E1
2012-05-17 01:00:58 20.947
```

How do I get only the 20.947 ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Double the square brackets.

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=rnorm(5))
d1$b[[3]]
```

That should do it. But there are many ways to do this...

Comment: OR maybe you can use [this web page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html) to help you

Answer (score 6):

```
as.double( testdfcompound_1$E1[1])
```

Then you get the value also. Was "*2012-05-17 01:00:58*" and "*E1*" not the row and column name in your case?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting the output in that format is because,

```
dataframe$field[i]
```

returns a factor.
I solved the problem by passing this into the function as.vector(), which returned the first value.

```
as.vector(dataframe$field[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

I find this a bit puzzling. What does `str(testdfcompound_1)` show? *If* you have data frame, your subsetting should work.

A small example that produces a **data frame** that *looks* like your sample data, and for which the subsetting works.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(E1 = rnorm(5) + 20, E2 = rnorm(5) + 2)
df
rownames(df) <- Sys.time() + 1:5
df
# looks pretty similar

df$E1[1]
# returns the number only.
```